# vscodeのSFTPでアップロードすると、かなり上の階層にアップロードされてしまいます。独自ドメイン以下の層にアップロードしたいです。

Tags: vscode, sftp

"remotepath": "/home/ice888/siteof.net/public_html/mosya",

このmosyaの階層にアップロードしたいのですが、上のリモートパスでも、ice888の階層にアップロードされてしまいます。

文字列を変えたりして試行錯誤しましたが、変わりません。

独自ドメインが、siteof.netなのですが、ドメインの設定が原因で下の階層にアップロードされないのでしょうか？。サーバーへの紐づけはきちんとされています。

誰かわかる方教えてください。

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「vscodeのSFTP」とは、この拡張機能を差していますか？ https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。はい、その通りです。

Answer (score 2):

## 原因

質問に提示されている設定では、 `remotepath` のようにすべて小文字になっています。しかし、該当の拡張機能のドキュメントでは、 `remotePath` のように `P` が大文字になっています。

接続やファイルのアップロードは正常に出来ているにも関わらずファイルの書き込み先が違うという問題から、この大文字小文字の間違いを拡張機能側が気づいていない（ため、 `remotePath` が設定されていないと認識して、デフォルトの場所にアップロードしている）と思われます。

```
{
    "name": "Profile Name",
    "host": "name_of_remote_host",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "port": 21,
    "secure": true,
    "username": "username",
    "remotePath": "/public_html/project", // <--- This is the path which will be downloaded if you "Download Project"
    "password": "password",
    "uploadOnSave": false
}
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp

## 解決方法

`"remotePath": "/home/ice888/siteof.net/public_html/mosya",` のように修正してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すぐにやってみます。